# Probability (Checking if my answers are correct)

Tags: probability, statistics, education

> Please check if my answers are correct
>   and please show me how to answer this using equation because I answer this question using listing method

Two dice are rolled. What is the probability of getting

1. a 4 and a 6?
2. not 3 and a 5?
3. the same number on both dice?
4. a sum of 8?
5. a sum of 3 and 4?
6. a pair where the first number is less that the second number?
7. a sum of 12?
8. a sum of 13?
9. (3,4) or (6,2)?
10. two even numbers?
11. a sum less than 8?
12. a sum greater then 2?

My answer:

1. 4/9
2. 4/9
3. 1/6
4. 7/36
5. 5/36
6. 5/12
7. 1/36
8. 0
9. 1/18
10. 1/4
11. 7/12
12. 11/12

Comment: Just picking one out:12. What is the probability of getting a sum of exactly $2$ (i.e. a $1$ and a $1$, see number 1.)?

Comment: @Elz12345 Would be great if you say how did you calculate each.